# Reducing the pixels-per-inch (PPI) of an image results in same file size

Tags: imagemagick, user-experience, image-editing, ppi, pixel-density

### Summary

I'm attempting to use ImageMagick to produce copies of an image with a range different pixel densities to increase the user-experience of my front-end projects.

### Problem

After running the script, the respective PPI is successfully converted but I am expecting the file sizes to be different, as detail is being removed and based on **prior research** from [this article](https://99designs.com/blog/tips/ppi-vs-dpi-whats-the-difference/#:%7E:text=Because%20increasing%20the%20PPI%20increases%20the%20size%20of%20your%20file%2C%20you%20will%20want%20to%20use%20a%20high%20PPI%20only%20when%20necessary.), but they are all the same (or similar).

### Base case

The base file has the following `identity` stats:

```
File: Image.JPG
 Resolution: 4896x3672
 PPI: 300,300
 Size: 7018920B
---------------------
```

### Steps to reproduce

I run the following commands:

```
convert Image.jpg -density 144 -units PixelsPerInch Image_2x.jpg
convert Image.jpg -density 72 -units PixelsPerInch Image_1x.jpg
convert Image.jpg -density 4 -units PixelsPerInch Image_0x.jpg
```

### Results

Then I check the `identity` stats once again with the following output:

```
File: Image.JPG
 Resolution: 4896x3672
 PPI: 300,300
 Size: 7018920B
---------------------
File: Image_2x.jpg
 Resolution: 4896x3672
 PPI: 144,144
 Size: 7019690B
---------------------
File: Image_1x.jpg
 Resolution: 4896x3672
 PPI: 72,72
 Size: 7019690B
---------------------
File: Image_0x.jpg
 Resolution: 4896x3672
 PPI: 4,4
 Size: 7019690B
---------------------
```

We can see that the PPI has changed for each respective image but the file sizes are all the same.

Comment: You're only changing the physical size of a single pixel, to change the file size you'll have to remove/add pixels, i.e. rescale the resolution, you can then adjust the ppi as well to make the picture appear the same size.

Comment: PPI is metadata - it tells whatever is rendering the image how to scale it, the data in the file doesn't change.

Comment: JPGs are not affected by -density except when printing.  -density is used to enlarge vector formats such as PDF, not raster formats such as JPG or PNG